# Scipy's griddata method always fails

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to use the [griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata) method in Scipy to perform bicubic interpolation on a set of data. However every time I try I get the ValueError 'Buffer not C contiguous'.

The weird thing is that I'm running the example algorithm that they give and it still fails:

```
def func(x, y):
    return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2

def bicubic():

    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j]
    points = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
    values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])

    data = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
    return data
```

The stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 135, in <module>
    ZI = bicubic(xv,yv,values,gridx,gridy)
  File "/Users/Velox/Dropbox/Uni/Masters Project/Data/OpenSense/bicubic.py", line 14, in bicubic
    return griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py", line 187, in griddata
    ip = CloughTocher2DInterpolator(points, values, fill_value=fill_value)
  File "interpnd.pyx", line 803, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.__init__ (scipy/interpolate/interpnd.c:8584)
  File "interpnd.pyx", line 478, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.estimate_gradients_2d_global (scipy/interpolate/interpnd.c:6644)
ValueError: Buffer not C contiguous.
```

The versions of Numpy and Scipy are `1.8.0.dev-665a00a` and `0.13.0.dev-61f05fe` respectively.

Does anyone have any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: So it seems that the version of scipy and numpy that I had was out of date. Updating those libraries solved the problem. Versions are now `1.8.0` and `0.13.3`.

Comment: Yes, it's better to use released versions rather than (out-of-date) development versions, as the former are better tested against each other.

Comment: Definitely. I was fairly sure I had. Turns out it was a conflict between the version installed with homebrew pip and an old version installed with pip on the default python which ships with OS X.

Comment: so now it works, so this one can be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was an issue with an out of date version of numpy. The bug can be seen here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2956