# scikit-image transform ValueError: Buffer not C contiguous

Tags: python, numpy, buffer, scikit-image

I'm using the skimage transform module's `resize` method.

Not always, but sometimes, I'm getting an error on this line:

```
candidate = resize(np.copy(img[candidate_box[0]:candidate_box[2],candidate_box[1]:candidate_box[3]]), (50,100))
```

It tells me:

```
ValueError: Buffer not C contiguous
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811633/scipys-griddata-method-always-fails

Comment: Could you please provide a self-contained snippet that shows this behavior?  That should not happen, and if it does it is a bug that I'd like to fix.  Resizing non-contiguous arrays works on my system.

Answer (score 2):

Reshaping (and other operations) will sometimes disrupt the contiguity of an array. You can check whether this has happened by looking at the `flags`:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2).T
>>> a.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False # reshaped array is no longer C contiguous
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Try making a C contiguous copy of the array with [`np.ascontiguousarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html):

```
 >>> b = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
 >>> b.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True # array b is a C contiguous copy of array a
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

The function returns an array with the same shape and values as the target array, but the returned array is stored as a C contiguous array.

Comment: Where do you suggest I add the ascontiguousarray part? I'm trying it like this: `candidate = resize(np.ascontiguousarray(img[candidate_box[0]:candidate_box[2],candidate_box[1]:candidate_box[3]]), (50,100))`

Comment: @user961627 Yes, if `resize` requires the array to be C contiguous, that seems like a good place to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a error may raise this exception. Make sure your region is **within** your image. For example, let's say your image is 300x200, and your region is [199:299, 100:199]. Note 299>200. If you perform resize(image[100:199, 199:299]), you will see this error.

Hope it could help you.